# How to start a remote process on a windows system within a HTML5 application

Tags: windows, html, mobile, remote-access

We would like to start a remote process on a Windows System within a HTML5 application.

On Windows Systems such a Task could be solved like e.g. described [here](http://www.technospot.net/blogs/how-to-start-and-end-process-on-a-remote-computer/).

But how to solve such a task e.g. on android Devices?

Any idea whether a generic approach in HTML5 exists to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved this issue by implementing a Java Web Service which is listening on the Windows System. –